# I want migrate only product, customer, purchases in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, customer, purchase-order, migrate

I built a new working magento 2 store. I want to migrate only products, customers, purchases in the old store magento 2 hope to get everyone's help and suggestions. Thanks for all.